# I want to make query to read subject score of student to mark

Tags: sql-server

I have database in SQL Server 2012 with two tables

The first table columns is :

```
 | Student_ID , Subject_ID , Subject_score , Subject_mark |
 |--------------------------------------------------------|
 |     1      |    1       |     92        |     ?        |
 |     1      |    2       |     88        |     ?        |
 |____________|____________|_______________|______________|
```

And the second table columns is :

```
 |Score_ID | Subject_mark |
 |________________________|
 |  100    |     A+       |
 |  95     |     A        |
 |  90     |     B+       |
 |  85     |     B        |
 |  80     |     c        |
 |  75     |     E        |
 |_________|______________|
```

I want to write a query to get `Subject_mark` from the second table and put it in `Subject_mark` in the first table

```
select from Subject_mark on table_1 ranged from table_2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that marks are classified at a difference of 5 marks each, this should work.

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.Subject_mark = CASE WHEN t1.Subject_score < 75 THEN 'E' ELSE t2.Subject_mark END
FROM FirstTable t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN SecondTable t2 ON t1.Subject_score <= t2.Score_ID AND t1.Subject_score > t2.Score_ID - 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm on my phone, so I'll have to check this later, as something seems a bit wrong about it, but try something like

```
Update table_1 
Set Subject_mark = (select Subject_mark from table_2 
                    where Score_ID <= (select Subject_score) 
                    and Score_ID > (select Subject_score - 5))
```

---

Sample execution with given sample data:

```
DECLARE @FirstTable TABLE (Student_ID INT, Subject_ID INT, Subject_score INT, Subject_mark VARCHAR(3))

INSERT INTO @FirstTable (Student_ID, Subject_ID, Subject_score, Subject_mark)
VALUES 
 (1, 1, 92, NULL),
 (1, 2, 88, NULL)

DECLARE @SecondTable TABLE (Score_ID INT, Subject_mark VARCHAR(3))

INSERT INTO @SecondTable (Score_ID, Subject_mark)
VALUES
 (100, 'A+'),
 (95 , 'A'),
 (90 , 'B+'),
 (85 , 'B'),
 (80 , 'C'),
 (75 , 'E')

UPDATE @FirstTable 
SET Subject_mark = (SELECT Subject_mark 
                    FROM @SecondTable 
                    WHERE Score_ID <= (SELECT Subject_score) AND 
                          Score_ID > (SELECT Subject_score - 5))

SELECT * FROM @FirstTable
```